# Изменить значение в запросе MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Имеется запрос:

```
$sql = "UPDATE other SET time = DATE_ADD(time,INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) WHERE id = 1";
```

Необходимо сделать рандомный выбор минуты (например 2, 3, 4, 5). 
Подскажите как это можно записать в запросе, или создать переменную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rand = rand(1, 5);
$sql = "UPDATE other SET time = DATE_ADD(time,INTERVAL $rand MINUTE) WHERE id = 1";
```